# Is doubting a person who is trying to prove the Qur'an scientifically accurate a sin or disbelief?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, science, kufr

I was reading a text from IslamQA about a French man who examined the Quran, Torah and Bible and found the Quran to be scientifically accurate but not the Torah and Bible. As I read, I started to doubt this person for no reason. I repeatedly kept looking at his name to check whether or not he was someone I recognized. I repeatedly read sentences to check if this man was knowledgeable. I asked myself whether or not this person was already a Muslim. In other words I doubted a person who tried to prove that the Quran is scientifically accurate.

Have I sinned or disbelieved?

Comment: I guess you are talking about Maurice Bucaille https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Bucaille. Well if it is him: you should know that he was a doctor not a scientist, so in case of facts which are related to medicine he might be credible, but outside this field i won't take him as a reference either. And you should know that he worked as a physician for king Faisal and some family members of Anwar Sadat. And i have doubts about the so called "Scientific miraculousness of the Holy Quran" as QUran for us is a fact and scientific theories may change over time!

Comment: _Have i sinned or disbelieved?_ --- No, it is OK to question and be suspicious about other people's claims.

Answer (score 3):

If [Bozo the Clown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bozo_the_Clown) was trying to prove the Qur'an scientifically accurate, do you think it would be problematic to doubt him?

It's not disbelief.  It's not the Qur'an you're doubting, it's the person's claims about the Qur'an.  In fact, the Qur'an encourages Muslims to investigate in these circumstances:

> O you who have believed, if there comes to you a disobedient one with information, investigate, lest you harm a people out of ignorance and become, over what you have done, regretful.  -- [Qur'an 49:6](https://quran.com/49/6)

[Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/14212) goes into much detail on this topic, writing *verifying news is required according to sharee’ah*.  So, if you go by this ruling, not only is it not disbelief, it's not even haram; it's obligatory.

---

Also, we don't simply slip up and end up a disbeliever; it needs to be done intentionally.  In the [Open Letter to Al-Baghdadi](http://www.lettertobaghdadi.com/), a large number of scholars worldwide endorsed a document in response to ISIS leader [Al-Baghdadi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Bakr_al-Baghdadi)'s behavior; they write:

> ... disbelief requires the intention of disbelief, and not just absentminded words or deeds

Some other fatawa that repeat the idea that disbelief requires intention: [MuftiSays](https://www.muftisays.com/qa/question/4144/kufr-or-not.html), Islam Q&A ([1](https://islamqa.info/en/42505); [2](https://islamqa.info/en/123484); [3](https://islamqa.info/en/196032); [4](https://islamqa.info/en/10843)), [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=246388)